# Problemas com a query, eu acho, mas não dá erros de php

Tags: php

O form com as textboxes não está a ser mostrado

```
$session_Nome = $_SESSION['nome'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "aeac";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

 //Check connection

if (!$conn) {
        die("Falha na ligação: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    $sqla = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE $session_Nome='username_Admin'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);
    if ($result) {
        while($rowa= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo 'Nome: <input required type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $session_Nome; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>
            Email: <input required type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $rowa["email"]; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>
            Senha: <input required type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $rowa["password_Admin"]; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muda essa linha `$rowa= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` por `while($rowa= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo problema

Comment: Porque é que está a usar `<?php` dentro das `plicas`? sempre que imprimir uma uma variável php dentro de uma string utilize as aspas `duplas`. `<?php echo "Bla bla $minhastring[qualquercoisa] "; ?>`

Comment: @IazyFox, Ta usando sim

Comment: @RedCandy qual é a linha 86?

Comment: A linha 86 é Email:'<input required type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $rowa["email"]; ?>"style="width: 300px;"><br><br><br>

Comment: Neste momento não está a mostrar o form, portanto penso que seja problemas na query?

Comment: Posta um var_dump da variável $sqla

Comment: string(51) "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE RedCandy='username_Admin'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nessa linha

```
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE $session_Nome='username_Admin'";
```

troca as aspas simples de lugar

assim:

```
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE '$session_Nome'=username_Admin";
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!